# Javascript includes() failing

Tags: javascript, arrays, equality

Why are the last two console.logs showing false?

```js
const a = 'one';
const b = 'two';
const myArray = [[ 'one', 'two'], ['three', 'four'], ['five', 'six']];
console.log([a, b]);
console.log(myArray[0]);
console.log(myArray.includes([a, b]));
console.log(myArray[0] === [a, b]);
```

Comment: You should post your code as a snippet in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in JavaScript arrays and objects are compared by reference and not by value.

One solution I suggest is to use JSON.stringify()

```js
a = ["a", "b"]
b = ["a", "b"]

console.log(JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(a)) // return true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first convert the array (object) to a string using `JSON.stringify()`, then compare the string:

```js
const a = 'one';
const b = 'two';
const myArray = [
  ['one', 'two'],
  ['three', 'four'],
  ['five', 'six']
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray[0]) === JSON.stringify([a, b]));
```

You can also run through the separate values using `every()` and compare them like this:

```js
const a = 'one';
const b = 'two';
const myArray = [[ 'one', 'two'], ['three', 'four'], ['five', 'six']];

const isequal = [a, b].length === myArray[0].length && [a, b].every((value, i) => value === myArray[0][i]);
console.log(isequal);
```

Comment: That's great if you know it's in the array and what index it's at.

Comment: Yes indeed they would have to be in the right order

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.includes()` and triple equal operator `===` work with **references**, they don't compare the elements of the arrays, they compare the array references themselves:

```js
console.log([] === []); // false

const a = [];
const b = a;

console.log(a === b); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript are Objects and Objects comparison will always return false if the referenced objects aren't the same.

If you want to compare arrays you have to write a function for this or use isEqual func from lodash

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual

Comment: "always return false" is only true for NaN, not for objects.

Comment: *Objects comparison will always return false* No, objects comparison will return true if the referenced object is the same.